# Selecting a single/multiple Objects and moving them using coordinates in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to select a single/multiple objects and translating them using x,y,z coordinates panel. What I have done already is moving them to a specific coordinate, but not translating. In-order to translate them, I must get the current xyz coordinates of the selected objects and add to them the xyz coordinates which the user have written into the panel. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using TMPro;

public class InstantiateWithButton : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject[] prefabs = null;
public Camera cam = null;

public GameObject XYZPanel;

// public Vector3 newposition;

public float xPos;
public float yPos;
public float zPos;

public TMP_InputField inputx;
public TMP_InputField inputy;
public TMP_InputField inputz;

public GameObject target;

public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject> ();


void Start()
{
    XYZPanel.SetActive(false);
    inputx.text = 0.0f.ToString();
    inputy.text = 0.0f.ToString();
    inputz.text = 0.0f.ToString();

}

void Update()
{
    InstantiateObject();

    xPos = float.Parse(inputx.text);
    yPos = float.Parse(inputy.text);
    zPos = float.Parse(inputz.text);

}

public void InstantiateObject()
{
    if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
        {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "atom")
            {
                Instantiate(target, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            }
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Object")
            {
                XYZPanel.SetActive(true);
                targets.Add(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }

        }   
    }

}


public void moveObject()
{

    foreach(var target in targets)
    {
        target.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);
    }
    targets.Clear();
}





}
```

Comment: I don't see where you call `moveObject` ..

Comment: I assigned it only to a button in-order to submit the move only. @derHugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to **add** the vector instead of setting it then simply replace

```
target.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);
```

by

```
//                        |
//                        V
target.transform.position += new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);
```

or alternatively if it is easier to read for you use according method [`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

```
target.transform.Translate(new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos), Space.World);
```

---

If you rather want hem all to move independently in their according **local space** then rather use

```
target.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos);
```

or accordingly

```
target.transform.Translate(new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zPos));
```

Comment: This worked fine, thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

`transform.position` contains the current position. so your update function would look like

```
void Update()
{
    InstantiateObject();

    xPos = transform.position.x + float.Parse(inputx.text);
    yPos = transform.position.y + float.Parse(inputy.text);
    zPos = transform.position.z + float.Parse(inputz.text);
}
```

---

By the way, you don't need to Update the position all the time, you can use the events from the InputFields.
Make a function like

```
public void PositionChanged(string newPos)
{
    xPos = transform.position.x + float.Parse(newPos);
}
```

and assign it in Unity:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what the function will do

Comment: Your answer is working fine if I selected one object only, but if I selected multiple objects they are all replaced to the same position. What I am looking for is checking each original position of the objects selected which are in the targets array and then adding to it the translation needed.